# Supremum of $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $S$ be the set of all tuples $(x, y) $ with $x, y$ non-negative real numbers satisfying $x+y=2n$,for a fixed $n\in \Bbb{N} $. Then the supremum value of $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$ on the set $S$ is

1. $3n^2$
2. $2n^6$
3. $4n^6$
4. $n^6$

My thinking : take $f(x, y) =x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$ then express $f(x, y) $ as a function of $x$ by putting $y=2n-x$. Then applying calculus we can find the maximum for some value of $x$.
But calculation will be cumbersome. Is there any smart way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the AM-GM inequality, we have
$$xy \leqslant \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) ^2 =n^2,$$
and
$$xy(x^2+y^2) \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{2xy+(x^2+y^2)}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}\right)^2 = 2n^4.$$
Therefore
$$x^2y^2(x^2+y^2) \leqslant 2n^6.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: In a situation like this, it seems intuitively plausible that the maximum is at the symmetric point ($x=y=n$) (since the other special point ($x=0$) clearly is not the maximum).

To test this, rewrite the variables as $x=n+d$, $y=n-d$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Those substitution gives $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)= (n^2-d^2)^2.4nd$.what to do next?

Comment: @Math-Learner are you sure about the second factor? (Hint: For $d=0$, is $x^2+y^2=0$?)

Comment: Yes sorry for mistake that would be $2( n^2-d^2)^2 (n^2+d^2)$

Comment: @Math-Learner indeed, and now you have $2( n^2-d^2)^2 (n^2+d^2)=2( n^2-d^2) \cdot ( n^2-d^2)(n^2+d^2)$ ...

Comment: So the supremum will be attained at $d=0$. This is my observation. Also it can be shown using calculus. Is there any other way to describe the fact more logically?

Comment: @Math-Learner I'm not sure what you mena by more logically, but the reason for the intuition is that there are obvious symmetries under $x\to -x$, $y\to -y$ and $x\leftrightarrow y$, and the invariant subspaces are natural places for extrema

Comment: But I have one question in mind. Why this kind of symmetry leads to maximum value? I mean does finding minimum value is also possible using this symmetry?

Comment: @Math-Learner Of course, $x=0$ is another invariant subspace and the minimum. Consider such a subspace. The symmetry means that on a path orthogonal to the plane, the function cannot be lower on one side than on the other, or in other words, on the plane, we have an extremum

Answer (score 1):

This is a good opportunity to use Lagrange's multipliers method:

Let $g(x,y)=x+y-2n$. We have

$$\nabla g=\langle 1,1\rangle \textrm{ and }\nabla f = \langle 2xy^2(y^2+2x^2), 2yx^2(x^2+2y^2)\rangle$$

At a maximum, $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are parallel, so $xy^2(y^2+2x^2)=yx^2(x^2+2y^2)$. If $x=0$ or $y=0$, we have $f(x,y)=0$, which his the minimum value, so we can assume that $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$. Therefore,

$$ y(y^2+2x^2)=x(x^2+2y^2) \iff y^3+2yx^2=x^3+ 2xy^2 \iff y^3-x^3=2xy^2-2yx^2$$

so $$ (y-x)(y^2+xy+y^2)=2xy(y-x)$$

This means that $x=y$ or $y^2+x^2-xy=0 \iff (y-\frac{x}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}x^2=0 \iff x=y=0$, which we excluded.

Therefore, $x=y$ at the maximum, so $(x,y)=(n,n)$. Substituting, the maximum value is $f(n,n)=2n^6$.

**Note:** to be totally rigorous, Lagrange's method only says that, if the maximum value exists, then $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are parallel at the maximum. The maximum actually exists here because $\{ (x,y) | x\ge 0, y\ge 0, x+y=2n \}$ is compact.